# Shouldn't atoms of the same element repel each other?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, electrostatics

Shouldn't the same type of atoms repel each other due to electrostatic charge?

Comment: Atoms contain equal amounts of positive and negative charge, so to a first approximation they neither attract nor repel. What would make you think otherwise? (On the other hand, when placed together, most atoms are able to shift their electron clouds to sit in the middle in such a way that the nuclei are attracted to the common electron cloud more strongly than the diffuse clouds repel each other, and this is what becomes a chemical bond.)

Answer (score 3):

No, atoms have the same number of protons and electrons so they have no net charge. On the other hand ions  (cations and anions) would be repelled or attracted depending on their net charge.

Atoms are bound together in a molecules by different means like covalent bonding, ionic bonding (which can be easily explained in terms of electrostatic forces) or metallic bonding.

Answer (score 1):

Atoms are electrically neutral. Because of this they shouldn't attract or repel each other - but atoms do show a slight attraction, which is the reason most molecules form. This is called the residual electromagnetic interaction.

In short, the positive parts of one atom attract the negative parts of the other, and vice versa. There is a good little diagram on this site which explains simply how it works - http://www.particleadventure.org/residual_m.html

Comment: What a fantastic link you gave. I would like everyone to see it. Its so good. Hats off.